# Holoviews .to Interface: How To Attribute cmap and range according to an input parameter

Tags: python, holoviews

Using the dataset `ds` defined below how can I attribute one colormap and its associated range per value of `channels` when rendering the holomap?

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')

data = np.random.rand(100, 100, 3,20)
times = np.arange(0,10,.5)
channels = ['a','b','c']
ds = hv.Dataset((times,channels,
                 np.linspace(0., 1., 100),
                 np.linspace(0., 1., 100),
                 data),
                kdims=['t', 'channel', 'y', 'x'],
                vdims=hv.Dimension('T', range=(0, .9)))
opts.defaults(
    opts.GridSpace(shared_xaxis=True, shared_yaxis=True),
    opts.Image(cmap='jet', width=300, height=300,colorbar=True,),)
ds.to(hv.Image, ['y', 'x'])
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution that uses `xarray` to manage the dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
import param
import panel as pn
import panel.widgets as pnw
import xarray as xr
hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')

data = np.random.rand(10, 3, 100, 100)
times = np.arange(0,10)
channels=['a','b','c']

da = xr.DataArray(
        data,
        [
            ("t", times),
            ("c", channels),
            ("y", np.linspace(0., 1., 100)),
            ("x", np.linspace(0., 1., 100)),
         ],
         )
ds = da.to_dataset(name="T")

class Parameters(param.Parameterized):

    select_channel = param.Selector(default=channels[0], objects=channels)
    select_time =    param.Integer(default=int(times[0]), bounds=(0, int(len(times)-1) ) )    

    @param.depends('select_time','select_channel')

    def plots(self):

        if self.select_channel == channels[0]:
            img = hv.Image(hv.Dataset(ds.loc[dict(c=self.select_channel,t=self.select_time)]))
            cmap = 'inferno'

        elif self.select_channel == channels[1]:
            img = hv.Image(hv.Dataset(ds.loc[dict(c=self.select_channel,t=self.select_time)]))
            cmap = 'jet'  

        else:
            img = hv.Image(hv.Dataset(ds.loc[dict(c=self.select_channel,t=self.select_time)]))
            cmap = 'gray'


        frame_width = 500 
        return img.opts( cmap=cmap, 
                         frame_width=frame_width, 
                         frame_height=np.int(np.round(frame_width * ds.dims['y']/ds.dims['x'],0)),
                         framewise=False, axiswise=False, colorbar=False, aspect='equal',
                         fontsize={'title': 16,})

obj = Parameters()

fire_dmap = hv.DynamicMap(obj.plots)
widgets_parameters = pn.panel(obj.param, parameters=['select_channel','select_time'],width=200)
app = pn.Row(widgets_parameters, fire_dmap)
app
```